# Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded in mac os

Tags: java, r, xlconnect

I got a problem when I called 'XLConnect' library in R.

> Loading required package: XLConnectJars JavaVM: requested Java version
>   ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead. JavaVM: Failed to
>   load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib JavaVM FATAL: Failed to
>   load the jvm library. Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for
>   'XLConnectJars', details:   call: .jinit()   error:
>   JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1
>
> Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded

This error happened after I installed XLConnect and wrote library(XLconnect).

I googled this problem but there are no proper solution in my case.
I have already installed Java 8 and checked java location in terminal.
I run R in mac OS X (10.10.5)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are your JAVA and R architectures matching? I mean, do you run 32bit R and 32bit JAVA , or 64bit R and 64bit JAVA? If they don't match (eg 32bit JAVA and 64bit R), that's the kind of errors you might expect.

Comment: I checked my Java and R, they are all 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

I solve the problem thanks to http://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-r-and-java-1-8-to-work-together-on-osx/